# radio button position when orientation changes

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner, screen-orientation

how to write code for `spinner` position is constant when we change the **orientation** from **portrait** to **landscape**.. For example in a `spinner` there are 4 items if i select the second position item after that 
when i change the **orientation** that must be at second position only [i used `savedInstanceState` method but i dint got the ans so kindly help me to resolve this iss]

Comment: I can't figure what does happen exactly to your view when you change the orientation. Would you please clarify? Also, take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233741/spinner-drop-down-list-and-screen-orientation-change-problem), maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-threa), and [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4936)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this useful tutorial - [How to handle Screen Orientation changes in Android](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/03/how-to-handle-screen-orientation.html)